# how can I get username and data returning from facebook login ios app

Tags: facebook, ios6, return, integration

I have integrated facebook successfully. Now my requirement is to take username and other info when returning back from facebook login to my app?
  can anyone tell me to get return string after comming back from facebook login

Comment: login to facebook and returning back after login by using facebook framework

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use account framework and SLRequest in ios 6.0.Check below the link.

> http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/IPhone_iOS_6_Facebook_and_Twitter_Integration_using_SLRequest